# SSL breaks socket.io

Tags: javascript, ssl, nginx, socket.io

I've been using socket.io to run a messaging service and everything has been working fine, right up until i encrypted the domain name where the socket.io server is hosted, now i get the "CORS blocked same origin policy reason: CORS request did not succeed"

The url works when unencrypted(using http) and breaks when encrypted and uses https.

The server is hosted on an ubuntu server using NGINX to proxy requests.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

server code:

```
const fs = require("fs")
const https = require('https')

const options =    {
    key: fs.readFileSync(
        "/etc/letsencrypt/live/talk.liven.online/privkey.pem"
    ),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(
        "/etc/letsencrypt/live/talk.liven.online/cert.pem"
    ),
    ca: fs.readFileSync(
        "/etc/letsencrypt/live/talk.liven.online/chain.pem"
    )
}


const http = https.createServer(options)

const io = require('socket.io')(http, { transports:['websocket', 'htmlfile', 'xhr-polling', 'jsonp-polling', 'polling']})

io.origins(["https://navigator.liven.online"])
io.on("connection", socket => {
    console.log("a user connected!")
    socket.on('disconnect', () => console.log('user disconnected'))
    socket.on('chat message', msg => io.emit("chat message", msg))
}
const port = process.env.PORT || 2001;
http.listen(port, port => console.log("listening on ${port}"))
```

client code:

```
// heavily redacted but i think this is all thats relevant
io.connect("https://talk.liven.online", {secure: true, rejectUnauthorized: false})
```

nginx block config

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/talk.liven.online/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name talk.liven.online www.talk.liven.online;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://localhost:2001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/talk.liven.online/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/talk.liven.online/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = talk.liven.online) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name talk.liven.online www.talk.liven.online;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Answer (score 1):

The NGINX configuration that you're showing is for plain HTTP, not HTTPS. It also proxies requests using HTTP, not HTTPS:

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:2001
           ^^^^
```

You have to let NGINX handle the SSL-part if you want to allow the client to connect to `https://...`.

Since the `socket.io` server is running on the same machine as NGINX, you can probably do the actual proxying over plain HTTP.

Comment: I appreciate the help mate, does this entail anything more than changing http://localhost to https://..? or am i getting this totally wrong (newbie to server config)?

Comment: @Red I think that you need to remove the first two `listen` statements in the config you post (the ones for port 80). So the first `server` block listens on port 443, and handles SSL, and the second `server` blocks listens on port 80, and redirects all requests to the HTTPS-part.